# Creating a blob using SharedAccessSignature

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

This may have been answered before but I couldn't find it..

Can a sharedAccessSignature (created with write policy on a container) allow clients to upload "new" blobs to the container ? By new I mean a blob that isn't already present in the container and the name/size etc is provided by the client..

Also if possible can someone point to some links that list down the entire process of "using" a SAS (not creating one). If this has been answered before then can some one point me to the link for the same ?

I went through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415.aspx) where they show writing to a blob which already exists in the container, but they don't show how to create a new blob.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, User can create new blob

Please visit this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.sharedaccesspolicy.aspx

Regards,
Vijay.

Comment: this link just tells me that its possible to create a container level SAS which I already know. I wanted to know how to use the SAS to create a blob not how to create a SAS..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried creating a new blob, but I have [a simple demo app](https://bmspublic.blob.core.windows.net/codesamples/SharedKey.zip) that shows how to allow a user to upload to a blob. I don't have time today but it might be adaptable to the container level.

Meanwhile, you can still use this approach and if you create it as a page blob, you can make it 1tb in size but won't be charged for the space unless its actually in use. So if the user only uploads 1mb, that's all you'll be billed for.